# Saving an undefined number of user input

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have created a program in JAVA that has menu Options, 1 to 5. Option 4 being "Add student". Where it asks a 4 questions

```
Questions: 
Please Enter student name:
Please Enter student course:
Please Enter student number:
Please Enter student gender:
```

After user has given these details, It will save into an array and ends the program. I am quite lost on how to save these details into an array.

This is my program where i tried to find a solution myself, But im relatively new to arrays and method myself.

```
public static void newstudent (String[] name,String[] course,int[] number,String[] gender)
    {  
    }
    public static void selection (int option) // Menu
    {
        switch (option)  
       {
           case 1:
               System.out.println("Display Student option");
               break;
           case 2:
               System.out.println("Search Student");
               break;
           case 3:
               System.out.println("Delete Student");
               break;
           case 4:
               //code for adding new student
               break;
           case 5:
               System.out.println("Exited");
               break;

           default:JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid option! Please enter in the range from 1 to 5.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

       }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Start of Menu loop Statement
        int option1 ;

       do{
       String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your option:\n"+"\n"+"1. Display Students\n"+"2. Search Students\n" + "3. Delete Students\n"+"4. Add Students\n"+"5. Exit ","DMIT Students",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
       option1 = Integer.parseInt(option);

       selection(option1);


       }while(option1 <1 || option1 > 5);
       // End of Menu Loop statement

    }

}
```

i tried doing a for loop to add +1 to these array everytime a user inputs all these details but the for loop will be stuck in a infinite loop. Is there any suggestions that i can get? or easier solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use arrays (the way you are using here) in the first place because you don't want to store the details of single student in four different places i.e. arrays. You can define a class Student with all the details you need and then it will be simple to add the details using class instances. Something like -

```
public class Student
{
    private String m_name;
    private int m_age;
    private String m_course;
    private String m_year;
    private String m_section;

    public Student( String name, int age, String course, String year, String section )
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_age = age;
        m_course = course;
        m_year = year;
        m_section = section;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return m_age;
    }

    public String getCourse()
    {
        return m_course;
    }

    public String getYear()
    {
        return m_year;
    }

    public String getSection()
    {
        return m_section;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "name: " + m_name + ", age: " + m_age + 
               ", course: " + m_course + ", year: " + m_year +
               ", section: " + m_section;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       int menuChoice = 4;
       do {
           System.out.println("\t\t\tStudent Record Menu");
           System.out.println("\t\t1. Add Student\t2. View Students\t3. Search Student\t4. Exit");
           try {
               System.out.println("Enter a choice: ");
               menuChoice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
               continue;
           }

           if (menuChoice==1)
           {
               System.out.println("Full name:");
               String name = input.nextLine();

               int age = -1;
               do {
                   try {
                       System.out.println("Age:");
                       age = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                       System.out.println("Enter a number!");
                       continue;
                   }
               } while (age <= 0);

               System.out.println("Course:");
               String course = input.nextLine();

               System.out.println("Year:");
               String year = input.nextLine();

               System.out.println("Section:");
               String section = input.nextLine();

               Student student = new Student(name, age, course, year, section);
               students.add(student);

           } else if (menuChoice==2) {
               System.out.println("Students:");
               for (Student student : students)
               {
                   System.out.println(student);
               }
           }
       } while (menuChoice<4);
    }
}
```

The above code snippet is referred from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63543/implementing-student-record-java-program).